# Filtering an ng-repeat by couchdb field

Tags: angularjs, couchdb, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently I am trying to filter my ng-repeat.  The filter should check the status of the couch DB field "_deleted" and show the article if "_deleted" is false, and remove the article from view if it is true.

```
ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:_deleted=true"
```

I know my syntax is incorrect, how can I format this filter correctly?  Please let me know if you guys need any more info.

-Edit-

I found a solution for this.  What I ended up having to do was create a function to check each item if it had the field, or rather the absence of said field.  Below is the function I created and is included in the controller.

```
$scope.trashCheck = function(article) {
return !article.hasOwnProperty('_deleted');
};
```

Once I had that set up I filtered my results like this.

```
<li ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:trashCheck">
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy from the filter docs (you use an object to do the match)

```
ng-repeat="article in articles | filter:{_deleted: true}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this didn't exactly fix my problem, but it did push me in the right direction.

Comment: Still working on it.  When I create a new database document, I am trying to give it a field of "_deleted: false".  I see that database is receiving the correct information, but it never sets up a field for _deleted.  So right now I am trying to make couch sets that for all new docs.  I am a complete newb to programming in general so it is most likely something silly I am missing.